# Replace() AMPscript is not replacing anything!

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

We are nesting `AMPscript` into a `content block` to insert products into email.  The AMPscript is pulling from a `Data Extension` where apostrophes are escaped as `&apos;`

What we're trying to do is swap the `&apos;`  with a regular apostrophe, and we're doing so using `Replace()`, but it's not working when contained in the `content block` but is working when pasted into an actual email

We then tried `TreatAsContent` but it doesn't seem to work.  We've tried combining both in the content block, even at the `SET` statement, but no luck.

**Is it possible to use Replace() in a content block and have it work within an email?**

Code in Content Block:

```
 SET @CartProductName1a = field(@row,"CartProductName1")
 SET @CartProductName1 = TreatAsContent(Replace(@CartProductName1a,"&apos;","'"))
```

Code in Email:
`%%=Replace(@CartProductName1,'&apos;',"'")=%%`

Comment: It absolutely can work in Content Block. Are you using an HTML block, or FreeForm? Also, have you tried another character in the string to determine that it's not the function, but instead something around the character "&apos;" that is not working?

Comment: HTML block.  I have not tested another string as yet, but will do so now.

Comment: @GeorgeRosedale can you paste a code and data sample?

Comment: updated the thread with sample code

Comment: tested another part of the string, and it worked just fine... I have a feeling the issue is that the HTML code is being rendered and so it can't find the character string as entered into the DE.