# Replace semi-colon not allowed in SQL - alternatives?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

Looking for solutions to my Replace() issue [outlined here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280248/replace-ampscript-is-not-replacing-anything), I thought an alternative might be a replace within SQL when moving data to the deployment data extension.

However, I've discovered that we can't Replace a string with a semi-colon as it is a reserved word.

```
Replace(FIELD,"apos;","'")
```

Is there a work-around in SQL Query builder to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, but it is not intuitive.

You will need to use the CHAR() function in SQL to do this as SFMC SQL Validator will not allow the reserved char `;` inside of your query no matter if it is escaped or inside a string.

So for example, you would do: `Replace(FIELD,'&apos' + Char(59), Char(39))`

Char(59) = ;
Char(39) = '

To help remove the complexity of trying to escape a single quote inside a single quoted string in SQL, I just used the Char() function again to represent the single apostrophe.

ref(http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: This worked! @Gortonington, add it to my tab!

Some additional notes:
- we have to include an "AS" statement when modifying the record (i.e., Replace(...) as Field_Name
- Gortonington left out the ampersand, but check your own work people!

Comment: added in the ampersand - I didn't even notice, I just copy/pasted across. My bad!